# How to generate a joomla user password using c#?

Tags: c#, joomla, md5

there is a question about php code to geneate joomla pass: [using php to create a joomla user password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727043/using-php-to-create-a-joomla-user-password) , any ideas how to do it on a c#?

Answer (score 1):

Theres some useful code here: http://www.marinovanderheijden.nl/post/2011/02/10/Validating-Joomla-15-passwords-with-C.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to port the [code Joomla uses](http://api.joomla.org/__filesource/fsource_Joomla-Framework_User_joomlauserhelper.php.html) into your own libraries as static methods. All you have to do in the end would be to take the PHP process:

```
$salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword(password, $salt);
$dbPassword = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

and convert it to C#:

```
string salt = Libraries.JUserHelper.genRandomPassword(32);
string crypt = Libraries.JUserHelper.getCryptedPassword(password, salt);
string dbPassword = string.Format("{0}:{1}", crypt, salt);
```