# Getting the users password in an onUserAfterSave event via a plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Is it possible to get the users unencrypted password in an onUserAfterSave even in a plugin? If so how?

I tried using $user->password_clear but that is blank.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using php to create a joomla user password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727043/using-php-to-create-a-joomla-user-password)

Answer (score 1):

Joomla use md5 hash to store password which is many to one mapping. So its almost impossible to recover JOOMLA password from md5 hash.

To change password just generate another md5 hash and replace it in database.

Answer (score 0):

You may retrieve the unhashed password using $_POST['password']