# Creating passwords for Joomla 2.5 with C#

Tags: c#, joomla2.5

I'm trying to create new passwords to Joomla 2.5 using C#.

I've tried the method where I hash some pass with `MD5CryptoService` and then concat a salt string with 32 characters, but without success.

```
var provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

var bytesFromPassword = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("my_password");
var hash = provider.ComputeHash(bytesFromPassword);

Random random = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks);
byte[] salt = new byte[32];
random.NextBytes(salt);

string hashTo64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
string saltTo64 = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);

var formattedPassword = string.Format("{0}:{1}", hashTo64, saltTo64);
```

Is something wrong with this code?

Do I need to change something?

Does Joomla 2.5 uses a new cryptography method that is different than this way I'm trying to do?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the salt you are creating is not used to salt the password. From my understanding of Joomla the password is saved as a hexadecimal string.

First you would have to include the salt in the `bytesFromPassword`

```
var salt = "ThereAreManySaltsButThisOneIsMine";
var bytesFromPassword = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("my_password" + salt);
var hash = provider.ComputeHash(bytesFromPassword);

var hashString = GenerateHexadecimalStringFromBytes(hash);
var formattedPassword = string.Format("{0}:{1}", hashString, salt);
```

Helper method to convert the byte array into hexadecimal string:

```
private static string GenerateHexadecimalStringFromBytes(byte[] hash)
{
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data  
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string. 
        foreach (byte t in hash)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(t.ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question using these two questions below:

[using php to create a joomla user password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727043/using-php-to-create-a-joomla-user-password)

[How convert byte array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string)

Hope it can help someone as well!