# Need support about password encryption in Joomla 3.x

Tags: c#, encryption, joomla, joomla3.4, joomla3.3

I need to implement an external login client using c# and .NET, but I'm having serious problems regarding with the encryption system the latest version of Joomla is using.

I've already figured out:

- Uses the Blowfish algoritm from newer versions of PHP.
- Uses the revised or corrected version of the algoritm (generates $2y$... strings)
- Joomla code adds a salt based on some user's info.

I'm having trouble mostly with the salt stuff, i cannot figure out where does it come from, or how is it generated.

I'm trying to search for info all over the internet, including here at StackOverflow, but all of them are incomplete. Joomla forums/documentation/wikis/source code also lack information, and google failed too. Regarding the Joomla source code, I'am not able to understand php code.

Could someone describe or point me to the correct direction, to help me out designing a coding a c# client program to perform a login check?

What i mainly do need is: Making my program to generate a hash from the uncrypted password for comparing it with the hash stored in the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304038/joomla-3-2-1-password-encryption/21304362#21304362

Comment: try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333417/joomla-3-4-password-generation-method/35337002#35337002

Comment: Hello!
Have you figured it out? Have you got something working well?
I would appreciate very much some tips :) 
Thanks!